# Disable single shortcut in firefox quantum

Tags: firefox, firefox-quantum

Is it possible to disable a single keyboard shortcut in firefox quantum? I would very much like to disable `ctrl-n` (or at least be able to capture and `event.preventDefault()` it) in firefox 57. Previous solutions use add ons that do not support firefox quantum.

Comment: Have you tried the ShortKeys addon? It seems to need many permissions, so I've not installed it, myself.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik shortkeys is not working. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 5):

Overwriting existing keybinds is not supported in Firefox Quantum (yet).

> If a key combination is already used by the browser (for example,
>   "Ctrl+Shift+R"), or by an existing add-on, then you can't override it. You will
>   be allowed to define it, but your event handler will not be called when the
>   user enters it.

See [this bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1320332) for more information.

Comment: There are several similar overlapping long sitting (2 years inactive, unassigned) bugs like the one above. 
There is also this:https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1303384